# How to send tokens to a wallet without exposing your Private Key (ethers.js)?

Tags: web3js, dapps, ethers.js, private-key, transfer

**Intro**: I am trying to create a web app where I can send some tokens from my personal account to another. I found out a possible way to achieve my goal using ethers.js in the following way:

```
// connect to metamask
let provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)

// define who signs the contract
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(your_private_key_string, provider);

// token infos
const tokenAddress = "0xEwgwegwdsB87f8Ebd86wegwegvweg"
      const tokenAbi = [
          // Some details about the token
          "function transfer(address to, uint amount)"
      ];

// define contract
const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(piaAddress, piaAbi, provider)

// send tokens from my wallet to someone else's.
tokenContract.connect(signer).transfer("receiverAddress", "500000000")
```

**Problem**: As you can see from the code, at one point I need to provide **your_private_key_string**. This would be fine if no one had access to my web app, but since I should be hosted in the internet, it would be exposed to all users thus making it vulnerable.

**Question**: Would you be able to suggest a smart and elegant way to perform the same task but avoiding to share my private key?

Note: the web-app is developed with Django in case it might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `python-dotenv` to store your private key in DjangoApp and fetch it from there. There is a good explanation and video tutorial in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61437799).